# WCF error on one server but not another: The socket connection was aborted

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, wcf

I'm receiving this error when I call a WCF service reference (net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService/mex):

```
CalculatorServiceReference.AnswerResultClient client = new CalculatorServiceReference.AnswerResultClient("NetTcpBinding_IAnswerResult");
rtn = client.ServiceUpdate(org_int, sData); // ERROR HERE
client.Close();
```

In the server:

```
public interface IAnswerResult
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool ServiceUpdate(string org_int, string delimitedString);
}
public bool ServiceUpdate(string org_int, string delimitedString)
{
...
}
```

I have an identical server and service that works fine and I can't seem to find any difference.  The error happens immediately, so it doesn't appear to be a timeout issue.

I tried the trace viewer but didn't see anything that's not here.  I'm not even sure what else I can post to help understand what is happening.  Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

The stack trace:

```
9/3/2018 7:52:44 AM:ERROR: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The operation completed successfully
EternaService: 151 org192.168.100.2:6256151
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:14:59.9969998'. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper& timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at CADEFileManager.CalculatorServiceReference.IAnswerResult.ServiceUpdate(String org_int, String delimitedString)
   at CADEFileManager.CalculatorServiceReference.AnswerResultClient.ServiceUpdate(String org_int, String delimitedString) in D:\Data\CADE.Net\FileManager\FileManager\Service References\CalculatorServiceReference\Reference.cs:line 67
   at CADEFileManager.FileManager.SendWCF(String org_int, String sData) in D:\Data\CADE.Net\FileManager\FileManager\FileManager.ashx.cs:line 9002
```

---

Well, I did another trace and found there are a number of references to timeouts.  Does this mean anything new?

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ConvertTransferException(SocketException socketException, TimeSpan timeout, Exception originalException, TransferOperation transferOperation, Boolean aborted, String timeoutErrorString, TransferOperation timeoutErrorTransferOperation, SocketConnection socketConnection, TimeSpan remainingTime)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadPacket(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.StartFrameHeader(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.ProcessRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)
System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.StreamConnection.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.SendPreamble(IConnection connection, ArraySegment`1 preamble, TimeoutHelper&amp; timeoutHelper)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.DuplexConnectionPoolHelper.AcceptPooledConnection(IConnection connection, TimeoutHelper&amp; timeoutHelper)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ConnectionPoolHelper.EstablishConnection(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ClientFramingDuplexSessionChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOpenOnce.System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ICallOnce.Call(ServiceChannel channel, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.CallOnceManager.CallOnce(TimeSpan timeout, CallOnceManager cascade)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
CADEFileManager.CalculatorServiceReference.IAnswerResult.ServiceUpdate(String org_int, String delimitedString)
CADEFileManager.CalculatorServiceReference.AnswerResultClient.ServiceUpdate(String org_int, String delimitedString)
CADEFileManager.FileManager.SendWCF(HttpContext context, String org_int, String sData)
CADEFileManager.FileManager.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: What does your logging on he service side tell you? Did it get called? Did it produce a result? Did it finish the call? Was there any exception?

Comment: Sorry, should have mentioned, Server is never reached.

Comment: If it's never reached, something is wrong (or not as expected) with the hosting. How do you host them? Where is the difference between the servers, where do you set the different URLs for the client?

Comment: Both are VM's in same virtual data center, same OS's. URLs are set in the client when the Service Reference is created, using "net.tcp://localhost:6256/CalculatorService/mex".  I started to add that service again and it does successfully find the service.

Comment: So they each go to their own machine?

Comment: Yes.  An .ashx page hosted on each server calls the WCF Service Reference in a self-hosted WCF Windows Service on the same server.

Comment: I'm afraid there is little we can do to help, you will need to log every little bit in service and client and figure out the difference between both your machines.

Comment: My mistake on the server.  I changed logging and got a new error on the server, A SecurityTokenValidationException: "The service does not allow you to log on anonymously.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to change the configuration to log on securely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution based on a comment in https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/896861/you-receive-error-401-1-when-you-browse-a-web-site-that-uses-integrate.

Windows Service Pack update includes a loopback check security feature that is designed to help prevent reflection attacks on your computer. Therefore, authentication fails if the FQDN or the custom host header that you use does not match the local computer name.

So, all I did was change the WCF link from localhost to the computer's name and it worked!!

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring "receiveTimeout" property for the binding.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="someBinding" receiveTimeout ="00:10:00">
          ...       
        </binding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Also see "closeTimeout", "sendTimeout" and "openTimeout" properties of the Binding class.

Comment: I tried that (and for netTcpBinding) but no change.  Using the debugger, the error is instant so it doesn't appear to be related to timing.. IMHO.

Comment: I did another trace and there are quite a few references to timeouts.  I edited the original post with the trace... mean anything new?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the port was open on that machine? Or maybe it is being used by another process?

You can try typing "netstat" in a command line interface to see the ports being used.

Comment: Netstat shows the port 6256 "Listening" on 0.0.0.0:6256 and [::]:6256... I'm not sure what that last one means.